# iPhone app external display window zooms in/out when running on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

We're writing an iPhone app that supports an external display via the 30-pin-connector-to-VGA adapter when used on the iPhone 4 or iPad. It is not a universal app. My problem is: when the app is running on the iPad and the user zooms the app to fill the screen, whatever is displaying on the external display also doubles in size. I would like to have the external display not change scale when the user presses the zoom in/out button on the iPad.

Does anyone know of a way to tell if an iPhone app is zoomed in/out on the iPad?

Can you get the size of the window/view being displayed on the iPad that compensates for the iPhone app's current scale?

Comment: How do you display the content on the external screen? Are these their own UIViews or do you copy the frame buffer via UIGetScreenImage()?

Comment: I have a separate UIWindow for each of the 2 screens (the main screen and the external screen). I have 1 EAGLView that I move from the main window to the external one when the external one becomes available and move it back to the main window if the external display ever disconnects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run an iPhone native application on the iPad it's executed in a kind of simulator. The double size is managed by this system and is virtual. Nothing can mesure this on the iphone app.